# Crystal Report grow horziontal

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

We can set grow property of a field so it will grow with vertical wtith the content, How can we grow it in horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

Make the field wider? Think about a page. You can only use the width of a page. Where as growing vertically you can keep growing onto the next page.